# How to parse the node information in the nodes directory by leveldb?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, python, leveldb, rlp

I want to get all the node IP addresses of ETH, so I need to parse the geth/nodes directory, but I can't find the specific data format and cannot parse it.

I found a same problem, but there is no solution:
[Format of LevelDB files in nodes directory? Trouble pulling contents with python leveldb API](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/format-of-leveldb-files-in-nodes-directory-trouble-pulling-contents-with-python)

My code:

```
import leveldb
import rlp

db = leveldb.LevelDB("../nodes")
for k in db.RangeIter():
    print(k)
    print(rlp.decode(k[0]))
    break
```

Result:

```
(bytearray(b'local:\xc6\x83\x00\xb8LX\xcc+\xcd\x98CDd\x96\x89R\x92\x1a\xaeV\xe1\x93\xfeV\x95)\t~$e\xfa|:seq'), bytearray(b'\x97\x08'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(rlp.decode(k[0]))
  File "PATH/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rlp/codec.py", line 235, in decode
    raise DecodingError(msg, rlp)
rlp.exceptions.DecodingError: RLP string ends with 41 superfluous bytes
```

I searched a lot of information and found that rlp.sedes needs to be specified when decoding. I can't determine which kind of sedes it is. I am a newcomer to ETH and I need help. Examples of parsing in other programming languages are also available.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea on how to do it with leveldb. But you could use the `admin.peers` from geth api/cli that return something like that:

```
[{
    caps: ["eth/61", "eth/62", "eth/63"],
    id: "08a6b39263470c78d3e4f58e3c997cd2e7af623afce64656cfc56480babcea7a9138f3d09d7b9879344c2d2e457679e3655d4b56eaff5fd4fd7f147bdb045124",
    name: "Geth/v1.5.0-unstable/linux/go1.5.1",
    network: {
      localAddress: "192.168.0.104:51068",
      remoteAddress: "71.62.31.72:30303"
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 17334052235346465000,
        head: "5794b768dae6c6ee5366e6ca7662bdff2882576e09609bf778633e470e0e7852",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}, /* ... */ {
    caps: ["eth/61", "eth/62", "eth/63"],
    id: "fcad9f6d3faf89a0908a11ddae9d4be3a1039108263b06c96171eb3b0f3ba85a7095a03bb65198c35a04829032d198759edfca9b63a8b69dc47a205d94fce7cc",
    name: "Geth/v1.3.5-506c9277/linux/go1.4.2",
    network: {
      localAddress: "192.168.0.104:55968",
      remoteAddress: "121.196.232.205:30303"
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 17335165914080772000,
        head: "5794b768dae6c6ee5366e6ca7662bdff2882576e09609bf778633e470e0e7852",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}]
```

[documentation here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#admin_peers)

The `remoteAddress` should be what you are looking for. But keep in mind that just the list of your node peers and not the whole list of ethereum nodes.